# Extracting data between </br> tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this html data which I need to parse to extract data from it.But it has so many  tags and data is also difficult too navigable for me.From below Html data i need to create a python dictionary list that will look like:

> [{"School":"Childs
>   play"},{"Place":"newyork"},{"Level":"four"},{"Country":"USA"},{"Level
>   Of Course":"Easy"}]

```
<div class="quick">
 <strong>School</strong><br /> Childs play <br /><br />
 <strong>Place</strong><br />
 <a href="Search.aspx?Menu=new&amp;Me=">newyork</a><br /><br />
 <strong>Level</strong><br />four<br /><br />
 <strong>Country</strong><br />USA<br /><br />
 <strong>Level Of Course</strong><br />Easy<br /><br />
</div>
```

I tried using beautifulsoup but didnt get success .Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the HTML is not ideally constructed for parsing, but it is possible to extract the data into a meaningful Python dictionary.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlString)

raw_data = soup.find(**{"class": "quick"}).contents
data = [x for x in raw_data if not hasattr(x, "name") or not x.name == "br"]
```

Using `if not hasattr(x, "name") or not x.name == "br"` first checks to make sure that the item is an instance of `NavigableString` and then checks that the element is not a `<BR>` tag.

`data` will then be of the format `[<KEY>, <VALUE>, <KEY>, <VALUE>]` from which it should be fairly trivial to extract the data.